# how to disable WYSIWYG for the body on certain content types on Drupal?

Tags: drupal, wysiwyg, content-type, cck

Is there any way to specify that the WYSIWYG wil not load for certain content types (I'm interested mainly in the body content) but it wouldn't hurt to apply this to the CCK content as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [CK editor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) then go to

> /admin/settings/ckeditor/edit/Default

to change the setting for the default profile, under visibility settings select include and enter the text aread ids for which you want the editor to be enabled.

And as the blog help says entering

> - blog@*.edit-body - matches all fields of type "blog" called
>     edit-body, on any page.
> - node/add/*.edit-user-* - matches fields starting with "edit-user-" on
>     pages starting with "node/add/

Comment: I'm using Wysiwyg 6.x-2.1 with CKEditor 3.4.2.6041,  but it seems that /admin/settings/ckeditor/edit/Default is not valid, it shows me the general settings page, .. , If I go to Wysiwyg settings /admin/settings/wysiwyg it shows 3 settings Filtered HTML, FULL HTML and PHP code, the first two are set to CKeditor, but I can't find the settings for CKeditor.., Nor can I find it into modules listing..... Is that a replacement for Wysiwyg ?

Comment: I installed the CKeditor module and it replaced the editor that I had....it's settings only apeared in wysiwyg plugin, ... So what do I do? remove the wysiwyg plugin?

Comment: I have been using just the ckeditor and I have no complaints. Moreover below every text area you have a message like "CKEditor: the ID for excluding or including this element is quotes@node/add/quotes.edit-body."So you can try it I suppose. What wysiwyg is gives you a standard interface and that might remove few options like the one I told you I suppose. But I am not sure

Comment: I did disable the wysiwyg, and left enabled just the CKeditor, looks nice, the only problem is that it keeps applying the editor in the exclusions.. don't know why..  I'm almost sure that my exclusion string in the default is ok, the only thing that keeps complaining is that I haven't applied that for all the roles.. still for normal users It's applied and it's where I'm interested not to show the editor